# Authenticate User without sending plain password or hash to server

Tags: security, web, account

I want a user to be able to login into the account of a website. So, the user needs to authenticate but I don't want the possibility for the Server to get the password and have access to the stored data of the user. So, I am looking for a solution similar to RSA where the user for example receives a random string which then gets modified by the typed in password and then send back to the server and the server can decrypt the cipher text with a "public key" and when the decrypted and the random string matches the user is identified.

Maybe I have a solution but I'm not quite sure if this procedure leaves space for hacking the system. I had in mind that the user receives a random string and then performs with the password AES-256 and sends it back. (The random string would be updated after each successful attempt but on failed attempts the string can't be changed). Before anyone asks, I use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your problem really is that the any server receives the credentials, or if just the application server does not receive it, in last case, you can use the Oauth 2.0 authentication method.

This way, the application server will not receive the credentials, but a dedicated server for authentication. The application server will only receive the information if the authentication was successful or not.

Below is an example of what your architecture might look like.

[image]

You can take a closer look at the Oauth 2.0 documentation.

https://oauth.net/2/

I hope it helps, even if it was little